# Django request.Get.get('page') returning none

Tags: python-3.x, django, web, django-views

Trying to  use a paginator in a view. Getting none from page = request.GET.get('page'). As is, the call to paginator limits posts on a page properly, but any call to page sequence henceforth fails. Pages will display, but there will be nothing form pagination.html displayed. For clarity, Base.html is the base template from which all others inherit. list.html is the page where I expect to see pagination.html displayed.

This code is based off of the django manual. Is there something else that needs to be setup to give the requests querydict a key of 'page' or a better way to paginate?

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger


def post_list(request):
    object_list  = Post.published.all() #a list of the posts
    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 4) # 4 posts in each page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer deliver the first page
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range deliver last page of results
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request,'blog/post/list.html',{'page': page,'posts': posts})
```

pagination.html

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if page.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
        {% endif %}
        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page.number }} of {{ page.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>
        {% if page.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

base.html

```
#...
<div id="content">
            {% block content %}
                {% include "pagination.html" with page=posts %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
#...
```

list.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block title %}My Blog{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>My Blog</h1>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <h2>
            <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
                {{ post.title }}
            </a>
        </h2>
        <p class="date">
            Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
        </p>
        {{ post.body|truncatewords:30|linebreaks }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Do you by any chance fill the block named content in `blog/post/list.html`?

Comment: I believe I did. I have updated the post with list.html, which extends base.html and I believe is the fill for {%block content %}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you fill a block in a child template it replaces the super template's block's content (not literally the block named content here). If you want to keep the parent's block along with some extra content, you should use `{{ block.super }}`, i.e. `list.html` should be:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block title %}My Blog{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>My Blog</h1>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <h2>
            <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
                {{ post.title }}
            </a>
        </h2>
        <p class="date">
            Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
        </p>
        {{ post.body|truncatewords:30|linebreaks }}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```